# Gradle / Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gradle

I have a gradle project in eclipse (using STS plugin).  I have a properties file I want on my classpath.  This file is read during tests. In my project view, I put this file on

```
\src\test\resources\test.properties
```

When I run

```
gradle test
```

from the command line, this file is read.

But when I run eclipse it is not.

Comment: Would you mind attaching the build file? Just so I understand the problem, the file is in the src/test/resources folder, and it gets found when running tests from the command line, but not when you run the tests in eclipse?

Comment: `src/test/resources` must be marked as a source folder in Eclipse if you want its files to be on the Eclipse project build path. OTOH, Gradle's Java/Groovy/Scala plugin automatically includes this directory (if it exists) on the classpath for unit tests via the built-in `test` SourceSet. If you're not generating your Eclipse project files using Gradle, you probably should.

Answer (score 3):

To reiterate what superEb said in his comment:

`src/test/resources` must be designated as a source folder for Eclipse to include your properties file on the classpath for tests.

You can in include Gradle's Eclipse plugin to handle this for you automatically with:

```
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
```